# Word VBA to Highlight Specific Text (But Not Similar)

Tags: vba, ms-word

First off, yes, I've seen the other posts regarding highlighting text in a Word document. This question is different because I'm looking to exclude a very similar text string from the results.

So I have the script below that will highlight certain strings. The problem is that I'm searching code, and the convention that was used in creating variables was to use the string I'm searching for and prepend the @ sign to create the variable name. I only want instances that DO NOT have the @ sign at the beginning. For example, if I'm searching for dog, I want to highlight dog, or ,dog, but specifically exclude @dog. I've tried modifying the .Text criteria, but can't seem to get it quite right. Hopefully this is an easy answer for someone. Pertinent code is below; thanks in advance.

```
  Set rng = doc.Range
  With rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = VBA.Split(strSearchTerms, strDelim)(dblLCV)
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
```

So far the closest result has been using

```
.Text = "[!@]" & VBA.Split(strSearchTerms, strDelim)(dblLCV)
```

But that just highlighted everything except the @String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `@` symbol, it's a special character. `[!\@]` should do the job.

Comment: That didn't quite do it. Now ALL of the text is highlighted except for the @ signs. I'm looking for:

dog = highlighted
@dog = not highlighted
everything else = not highlighted

Thank you!

Comment: `[!\@]dog` highlights ` dog' but not ` @dog` for me.

Comment: My method of generating the search string (not shown here) was adding either a NULL or a zero length string to the search, causing my issue. Your answer solved what I asked - thanks for the push to take another look!

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, this got me what I needed:

```
.Text = "[,. ]{1,}" & VBA.Split(strSearchTerms, strDelim)(dblLCV) & ">"
```

I replaced the @ criteria with what knew would be there, as I couldn't ever get the "not @" logic to work. Hope this helps someone else!